# Can't deactivate virtual environment on Ubuntu-server

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-server

I have the code below where I've activated a virtual environment, and I am now trying to deactivate it.  I'm working on ubuntu server.  I created the environment with conda.  I'm not sure what the issue is.  I'm pretty sure I've done this exact thing on this server before.  I also tried launching jupyter notebook with no luck.  I haven't tried that on the server before, so I'm not sure if they're related.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
(base) username@server1:~$ source activate py27
(py27) username@server1:~$ jupyter notebook
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(py27) username@server1:~$ source deactivate py27
-bash: deactivate: No such file or directory
(py27) username@server1:~$ deactivate py27
deactivate: command not found
(py27) username@server1:~$ conda source deactivate py27

CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda source'.

(py27) username@server1:~$ deactivate source py27
deactivate: command not found
(py27) username@server1:~$ conda deactivate source py27
deactivate does not accept arguments
remainder_args: ['source', 'py27']
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked to deactivate the virtual python environment

```
conda deactivate
```